# Sample space for 8 employees chosen from 14 males and 6 females

Tags: probability

The homework question asks the following:

> There are twenty employees who work in a postal section of a company.
>   Fourteen of them are male and the rest are female. Eight of these
>   employees are selected to attend a course on a new delivery system.
>   The outcome of the experiment is the number of females in the selected
>   group. Give the sample space for the random experiment.

If $M$ denotes Males and $F$ denotes females, am I correct in saying the following is the sample space?

$S = \left\{ {\{ 6F,2M\} ,\{ 5F,3M\} ,\{ 4F,4M\} ,\{ 3F,5M\} ,\{ 2F,6M\} ,\{ 1F,7M\} ,\{ 8M\} } \right\}$

Comment: There are many different sample spaces available for many different problems.  As it currently reads your question is ambiguous.  The sample space you wrote is one among infinitely many possible sample spaces for your experiment and whether or not it is a *useful* sample space for your experiment depends on what sort of questions are being asked about it.  If the only questions being asked are "*How many females are in the selected group*" then your sample space is fine, but it could have been more simply written as $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Comment: Note that depending on your needs this might not be the most useful of sample spaces since it is not an equiprobable sample space, it is far less likely to get no females than it is to get two females for example.  Note also that your sample space makes no reference to who the specific people chosen are so it is useless for answering probability questions such as "Find the probability that John was chosen for the group with at least three women."  If neither of those complaints bother you, then your answer is again fine.